# Deserializing XML arrays with SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

I need to deserialize some XML I receive into an object. I use SimpleXML to do this. An example of some of the XML received is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coupons type="array">
  <coupon>
    <coupon_code>baz</coupon_code>
    <name>baz</name>
    <discount_type>percent</discount_type>
    <discount_percent type="integer">20</discount_percent>
    <plan_codes type="array">
      <plan_code>plus</plan_code>
      <plan_code>pro</plan_code>
    </plan_codes>
  </coupon>
  <coupon>
    <coupon_code>test</coupon_code>
    <name>Test</name>
    <discount_type>dollars</discount_type>
    <discount_in_cents>
      <USD type="integer">2000</USD>
      <EUR type="integer">1500</USD>
    </discount_in_cents>
    <plan_codes type="array">
      <plan_code>plus</plan_code>
    </plan_codes>
  </coupon>
</coupons>
```

In this piece of XML, there are 3 types of arrays: `<coupons>` is an array of `<coupon>`. `<coupon>` has 2 arrays as well: `<plan_codes>` (which is a flat array) and `<discount_in_cents>` which is an associative array.

How does my deserializer work: I create a SimpleXMLElement from the XML and pass it to a function `visitElement` which takes a SimpleXMLElement and the type, `array<Model\Coupon>` in this case, indicating it's an array of `Model\Coupon` objects.

In my `visitElement` I check if the type is an existing class, if so, I create a new instance of that class and get a configuration for that Model, the configuration tells me which children need to be deserialized to which object variable. `visitElement` looks like this:

```
public function visitElement($element, $type)
{
    // it is possible the element is not available
    if (!$element) {
        return null;
    } else {
        // get the value based on it's mapped type
        switch ($type) {
            case 'string':
                return $this->visitString($element);
                break;
            // ...
            // other cases
            // ...
            default: // catch other cases
                if (class_exists($type)) {
                    // We mapped to an existing class
                    return $this->visitModel($type, $element);
                } elseif ($this->isArrayType($type, $arrayType, $keepKey)) {
                    // We mapped to an array<type>
                    return $this->visitArray($arrayType, $element, $keepKey);
                } else {
                    // A type we can't handle
                    return null;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, I have a nice recursive way of deserializing other XML as well, that might have nested objects (For example, the Account XML has an Address object nested within).

My `Model\Coupon` is configured so that `<plan_codes>` and `<discount_in_cents>` are considered `array<string>` and `array<integer>` respectively.

This is my `visitArray` function:

```
protected function visitArray($type, $element, $keepKey = false)
{
    $value = null;
    $i     = 0;
    foreach ($element->children() as $key => $child) {
        $k         = $keepKey ? $key : $i++;
        $value[$k] = $this->visitElement($child, $type);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

This all works beautifully. I get an array of 2 `Model\Coupon` objects, with the second object having a discount_in_cents array that looks like ['USD' => 2000, 'EUR' => 1500], but it does NOT work for the plan codes...

When I var_dump those, I get

```
array (size=2)
  0 => null
  1 => null
```

and

```
array (size=1)
  0 => null
```

Is there any reason why looping over `<plan_codes>` would yield different results/children than `<coupons>` or `<discount_in_cents>`?

At the moment, I implemented a workaround in `visitArray` as follows:

```
protected function visitArray($type, $element, $keepKey = false)
{
    $value = null;
    $i     = 0;
    foreach ($element->children() as $key => $child) {
        $k         = $keepKey ? $key : $i++;
        $value[$k] = 'string' === $type ? (string)$child : $this->visitElement($child, $type);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the call to `visitArray()` that produces those results? Including parameter values, please.